# About correct use of sum in case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

There is a table "payments"

```
user_id     payment_time    amount    sale_type
1            2018-04-01      10       cash
1            2018-04-01      10       cash
1            2018-04-01      10       cash
1            2018-04-01      20       bank
2            2018-04-01      10       cash
2            2018-04-01      10       cash
```

Need the sum of cash.

I don't understand why this query gives wrong results:

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN p1.sale_type='cash' THEN p1.amount ELSE 0 END) 
as cash
FROM 
(SELECT distinct user_id, SUM(amount) AS amount, sale_type FROM payments where 
payment_time = '2018-04-01' group by user_id) p1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `sale_type` column to `GROUP BY` statement for the inner query and that should be `group by user_id, sale_type` for the correct results for your query style.

P.S. actually, I don't think you need a subquery.

The above query gives result as `60`, while

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN p1.sale_type='cash' THEN p1.amount ELSE 0 END) as cash
  from 
 (select distinct user_id, SUM(amount) AS amount, sale_type 
    from payments 
   where payment_time = date'2018-04-01' 
   group by user_id, sale_type) p1;
```

or

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN sale_type='cash' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as cash 
  from payments 
 where payment_time = date'2018-04-01'
```

gives `40` for resulting `cash` column

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58a2e6/4)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use 'Having' clause which is made for this purpose.

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS cash FROM payments
WHERE payment_time = '2018-04-01'
GROUP BY sale_type
HAVING sale_type= 'cash'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not need the `distinct` in your sub-query or the entire sub-query at all.

```
select p.user_id as id, sum(case when p.sale_type = 'cash' then p.amount else 0 end) as amount
from payments p 
where p.payment_time = '2018-04-01' 
group by p.user_id
```

or without `case`

```
select p.user_id, sum(p.amount)
from payments p 
where p.sale_type = 'cash' and p.payment_time = '2018-04-01' 
group by p.user_id
```